# Zend Framework 3 stylesheet in partials

Tags: php, zf3

I have a little problem with my partials in zf3, trying to add css in partial it doesn't work anymore as in zf2, this is my code:

```
<?php $this->headLink()->prependStylesheet($this->serverUrl() . '/path/to/css_file.css');?>
```

If anyone has any solution, I would greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the sweety echo function :)

```
<?php echo $this->headLink()->prependStylesheet($this->serverUrl() . '/path/to/css_file.css');?>
```

Comment: If i put echo works but...duplicate all css...they say...don't echo individual files

Comment: What i try to do: use view helper as widget system (view helper with view file)
Application\Widget\Init.php looks like:
`<?php
namespace Application\Widget\Widget1
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
class Init extends AbstractHelper{
  public function __invoke(){
    return $this->view->render('widget/widget1/view.phtml');
  }
}`
widget\widget1\view.phtml
`<!--some html -->
<?php $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('file.css') ?>`
the problem is: if I call this widget from layout.phtml, headLink is not call, but, if i call same widget in any other view, is ok load that css file